# c++ wrap a string reference in an ostream

Tags: c++, c++11, ostream

I have an object that returns a non const string reference. I'd like to pass this string reference to a method that takes a reference to an ostream, allowing that method to write to the string reference. Is there way to wrap a string reference in an ostream (using std or boost libraries) such that the string reference can be written to via an ostream?I do not want to use stringstream since that copies the string, thus not writing to the original.

For example.

Library A returns a string reference.
Library B take a reference to an ostream and writes data to it.

Is is it possible to somehow wrap the string reference returned by library A in an ostream such that library B can write to string held by library A.

```
int main() {
  std::string& foo(library_a.get_string_reference());
  //wrap foo somehow in an ostream?
  library_b.write_to_ostream(wrapped_foo)
}
```

Comment: What about simply using a `std::stringstream`? Is it essential that you have an external `std::string` reference to wrap in your class?

Comment: I am using two libraries that I do not control. Library A has a function that returns a non const string reference. LIbrary B has a function that takes a reference to a std::ostream and writes data to it. I'd like Library B to be able to write to the string reference returned by library A.

Comment: @user3472 I don't know about boost, but there is nothing in the standard library for this use case. So, to do what you are asking, you will have to write your own, or find a 3rd party, custom `std::basic_streambuf` descendant to wrap the `std::string&` reference. Then you can construct an instance of the base `std::ostream` class passing its constructor a pointer to an instance of that descendent class. If you write your own descendant, you can model it after `std::basic_stringbuf`, just replace the inner `std::string` variable with your `std::string&` reference.

Comment: "_I do not want to use stringstream since that copies the string, thus not writing to the original_" - If you use an `ostringstream` and then assign `str()` to the string reference you got from `A`, the string will be move assigned. I don't think you'll find that very costly.